# How to add drop down sub menu from database fields in the particular menu slug

Tags: menus, database, sub-menu

I am creating a menu(not in admin panel) in wordpress, and I want to add drop down menu from my database table fields in a particular menu slug?

How can I achieve that, using code?

I found the answer from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/ but this will add a main nav menu, but I want a sub menu from database.

For egs.: 
I have a `Gallery page` and their are `sub galleries` in the `Gallery`. Then after `gallery slug` the `sub galleries` should be added.

See this http://theme.crumina.net/photo/
I want same as `gallery nav menu`, hovering on `gallery menu` the `sub galleries` are shown.

**Remember** all these `sub galleries` came from `database table`

I have recently started on `wordpress`, so I don't know more about it.

Thank in advane.

Comment: Please enrich this question by what you have tried so far. It helps to show some research effort and be as concrete in asking as possible to maximize the likelihood of a quality answer.

Comment: Yes, it would be an interesting Question (deserving upvotes and a great Answer) if properly researched and formulated. Please, check this guide: [ask]. . . . . .